# Как правильно использовать псевдонимы в left join?

Tags: mysql

делаю такой запрос

```
SELECT
 `serial`.`id`,
 `serial`.`name_serial`,
 `serial`.`slug_serial`,
 `serial`.`nesting`,
 `serial`.`year`,
 `film`.`id`,
 `film`.`name_film`,
 `film`.`slug_film`,
 `film`.`nesting`,
 `film`.`year`,
 `mfilm`.`id`,
 `mfilm`.`name_mfilm`,
 `mfilm`.`slug_mfilm`,
 `mfilm`.`nesting`,`year`
FROM
 `fl_cat_serial`
LEFT JOIN
 `fl_serial` 
ON
  fl_cat_serial.id_serial = fl_serial.id 
LEFT JOIN
 `fl_film` 
ON
  fl_cat_serial.id_film = fl_film.id 
LEFT JOIN
 `fl_mfilm` 
ON
  fl_cat_serial.id_mfilm = fl_mfilm.id 
WHERE `fl_cat_serial`.`id_cat`=1
```

хотелось бы такие поля как name_seria, name_film, name_mfilm получать как name я так понимаю для этого нужно использовать псевдоним, но как не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы назначить псевдоним столбцу следует воспользоваться ключевым словом `AS`

```
SELECT
  `fl_serial`.`id` id_serial,
  `fl_serial`.`name_serial` AS name_serial,
  `fl_serial`.`slug_serial` AS slug_serial,
  `fl_serial`.`nesting` AS nesting_serial,
  `fl_serial`.`year` AS year_serial,
  `fl_film`.`id` As id_film,
  `fl_film`.`name_film` AS name_film,
  `fl_film`.`slug_film` AS slug_film,
  `fl_film`.`nesting` AS nesting_film,
  `fl_film`.`year` AS year_film,
  `fl_mfilm`.`id` AS id_mfilm,
  `fl_mfilm`.`name_mfilm` AS name_mfilm,
  `fl_mfilm`.`slug_mfilm` AS slug_mfilm,
  `fl_mfilm`.`nesting` AS nesting_mfilm, 
FROM
  `fl_cat_serial`
LEFT JOIN
  `fl_serial` 
ON
  fl_cat_serial.id_serial = fl_serial.id 
LEFT JOIN
  `fl_film` 
ON
  fl_cat_serial.id_film = fl_film.id 
LEFT JOIN
  `fl_mfilm` 
ON
  fl_cat_serial.id_mfilm = fl_mfilm.id 
WHERE
  `fl_cat_serial`.`id_cat`= 1
```

Причем псевдонимы вы можете назначать не только столбцам, но и таблицам. Тогда запрос получится более компактным.

```
SELECT
  s.`id` id_serial,
  s.`name_serial` AS name_serial,
  s.`slug_serial` AS slug_serial,
  s.`nesting` AS nesting_serial,
  s.`year` AS year_serial,
  f.`id` As id_film,
  f.`name_film` AS name_film,
  f.`slug_film` AS slug_film,
  f.`nesting` AS nesting_film,
  f.`year` AS year_film,
  m.`id` AS id_mfilm,
  m.`name_mfilm` AS name_mfilm,
  m.`slug_mfilm` AS slug_mfilm,
  m.`nesting` AS nesting_mfilm, 
FROM
  `fl_cat_serial`
LEFT JOIN
  `fl_serial` AS s
ON
  fl_cat_serial.id_serial = fl_serial.id 
LEFT JOIN
  `fl_film` AS f
ON
  fl_cat_serial.id_film = fl_film.id 
LEFT JOIN
  `fl_mfilm` AS m
ON
  fl_cat_serial.id_mfilm = fl_mfilm.id 
WHERE
  `fl_cat_serial`.`id_cat`= 1
```

Comment: вы немного не поняли мне надо что бы вместо name_serial, name_film,name_mfilm что бы я мог его использовать на выходе к примеру object->name

Comment: Назначайте псевдоним AS name и можно использовать object->name, но псевдоним должен быть уникальным. Двум столбцам назначить AS name не получится.

Comment: а через concat?

Comment: Да, можно, но этом случае вы получите строку CONCAT(s.name_serial, ' ', f.name_film, ' ', m.name_mfilm) AS name. Если у вас только одно значение принимает строковое значение, а остальные NULL, то можно воспользоваться функцией COALESCE: COALESCE(s.name_serial, f.name_film, m.name_mfilm) AS name

Comment: Большое спасибо очень помогли